# Angular Material Autocomplete is slow

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, angular-material

I have Angular Material Autocomplete setup so it runs an $http get request when the search text changes, the php side itself takes ~1 second, but the request overall takes 3 seconds! It's an autocomplete for north american cities (only 2000 rows in the table) so it's not exactly the query time (0.0025 seconds in phpmyadmin - there's even a full text index on the column being searched) that I'm worried about but the overhead angular adds. It's really laggy and if I just initially load the 2000 cities the browser lags when you type in the autocomplete!

How can I speed this up to work like a normal autocomplete?

Comment: [Breeze](http://www.getbreezenow.com/) might be a solution which can take the place of php in your angular app. But though, getting all the cities beforehand instead of requesting each time the user write is much efficienter i think.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into it, but as I mentioned, if I get all the data at once in the beginning, the browser becomes slow.

Comment: I just tried in my project and it loaded 7500 items in 4-5 seconds but when rendering 7500 items made Chrome slow for 2-3 seconds.